# FFPlay buffers packets even with -fflags nobuffer

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, video

So I am streaming an mp4 video using `ffmpeg` to another host where I read the stream with `ffplay`. Here are the commands I use:

For sending host with IP 192.168.1.1:

```
ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -strict 2 -preset ultrafast -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://192.168.3.1:5010 -sdpfile sample.sdp
```

For receiving host with IP 192.168.3.1:

```
ffplay -rtbufsize 0 -reorder_queue_size 0 -fflags nobuffer+fastseek -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i sample sample.sdp
```

Everything works well so far. Then I try to simulate a faulty link between the two hosts (either using `ip link set eth0 down` or throttle the bandwidth with `tc`) and I am expecting to see the results immediately.

For example, when I bring down the link between the two hosts I expect `ffplay` to stop the playback. However, that's not the case. `ffplay` keeps playing 7-8 seconds of video after the stream stops which means there is some kind of buffering somewhere.

Furthermore, when I restore the link I immediately see the UDP packets reaching the receiver but `ffplay` takes again another 10 seconds to start the video. I tried all the possible commands to turn off buffering on the `ffplay` side to no avail.

Is there a way to start/stop the playback immediately after the connection is lost/restored?

P.S. I also tried using RTMP which uses TCP but the results were even worse.

Answer (score 1):

OK after fiddling with the ffmpeg and ffplay options I found these to work as I wanted:

**Streaming side:** ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -s 640x480 -b:v 800k -bf 0 -codec:a mp2 -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 128k udp://192.168.3.1:5000

**Receiving side:** ffplay -probesize 32 -sync ext -fflags nobuffer udp://localhost:5000

The ffplay playback is immediately stopped when I bring the link that connects the two hosts down and starts again when the link is restored.